# When I switch on multilingual in Hugo, the main directory is redirected to the default language

Tags: redirects, hugo

When you configure the `defaultContentLanguageInSubdir` setting with `true`, it causes the site to automatically redirect to the default language version, `example.com/en`, when accessing the root directory, `example.com`.

However, I have concerns about potential routing conflicts because I intend to implement server-side routing based on users' country. Is it feasible to retain `defaultContentLanguageInSubdir` while disabling the routing feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create **alias.html** file under layouts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ site.Language.LanguageCode }}">
  <head>
    <title>{{ .Permalink }}</title>
    <link rel = "canonical" href = "{{ .Permalink }}">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={{ .Permalink }}">
  </head>
</html>
```

Normally these files appear and the contents are like this.

If you create it and then leave it blank, the above code will be disabled and the redirect will be cancelled.